# PHP - check if can get property

Tags: php

I have an application where I ran into a small problem. I have a class Header:

```
class ReportArtGroup extends JournalListElement {

    public $artGroupNum;
    private $artGroupAmnt;
    private $accDesc;

    function setArtGroupAmnt($artGroupAmnt) {
        $this->artGroupAmnt = MoneyHelper::centsToDollars($artGroupAmnt);
    }

    function getArtGroupAmnt() {
        return $this->artGroupAmnt;
    }

}
```

This is just an example class. Now let's say I want to check each of those properties for accessibility through a function, example accessible(). In particular accessible should act in the following way:

```
accessible($reportArtGroup->artGroupNum) // return true.
accessible($report->artGroupAmnt) // should return true because accessible through getter
accessible($report->accDesc) // Should return false because not accessible
```

How can I do this in PHP?

**Notes on problem:**

1. Using reflection and `getProperties()` I can choose to get the private properties only or the public properties only. Can't till now find a way where $artGroupAmnt is going to be returned among the public!
2. Thought about using `isset()` but of course isset in the public properties is dependent on whether or not the properties are set.

Any method through which I can either get all the properties that could be returned for an object (including magically using a getter) is perfect. Open as well to get all properties using reflection or whatever method and then check each one by one. The behavior mentioned above is imp though

Comment: https://github.com/nette/utils/blob/master/src/Utils/SmartObject.php but honestly I'd recommend not doing such stuff at all.

Comment: PHP has two native functions for this: property_exists and method_exists.

Comment: @jspit can you give an example with those. property_exists returns true for private properties

Comment: yes, you're right, did not test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the getter via Method call since there is no real (protecting) property support like in C#. (coming with php 7.4)

```
accessible($report->getArtGroupAmnt());
```

You can access member variables directly if they are public.

```
public $accDesc;
echo $instance->accDesc;
```

To have a special return value when not set, initialize them like

```
public $iAmTrue = true;
public $iAmNull = null;
public $iAmNullToo;
public $iAmZero = 0;
public $iAmEmptyString = '';
public $iAmEmptyArray = [];
```

So when accessing

```
var_dump($instance->$iAmEmptyArray);
```

You would get an empty array. Because they are public, consider it could be overwritten by

```
$instance->iAmEmptyArray = 'Hello World';
```

So you should write reliable getters and setters.

```
private $array;

public setArray($array = []):void {
      $this->array = $array;
}

public getArray(): array {
      return $this->array ?? [];
}
```

Modern IDE like PHPStorm can autocomplete this for you.

You may trick a bit using null coalesce operators. Make the member variables public and do this:

```
public $myArray;
public $myInt;
public $myBool;
public $myString;

$_array  = $instance->myArray  ?? [];
$_int    = $instance->myInt    ?? 0;
$_bool   = $instance->myBool   ?? false;
$_string = $instance->myString ?? '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isPropertyAccessible($obj,$property){
  return array_key_exists($property,get_object_vars($obj));
}

function isMethodAccessible($obj,$method){
  return in_array($method,get_class_methods($obj));
}

class test{
  private $private = 1;
  protected $protected = 2; 
  public $public;
  private function funcpriv(){}
  public function funcpub(){}
}
$obj = new test;

$results = [];
$results[] = isPropertyAccessible($obj,'notexists');
$results[] = isPropertyAccessible($obj,'private');
$results[] = isPropertyAccessible($obj,'protected');
$results[] = isPropertyAccessible($obj,'public');

$results2[] = isMethodAccessible($obj,'notexists');
$results2[] = isMethodAccessible($obj,'funcpriv');
$results2[] = isMethodAccessible($obj,'funcpub');

var_dump($results);
// array(4) { [0]=> bool(false) [1]=> bool(false) [2]=> bool(false) [3]=> bool(true) }
var_dump($results2);
// array(3) { [0]=> bool(false) [1]=> bool(false) [2]=> bool(true) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(property_exist($object,'propertyName'));
```

Check our object

```
if(property_exist($reportArtGroup,'artGroup'))
```

Comment: This returns true  for private properties